# Как передать статические файлы при использовании сокетов?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ребят, пытаюсь передать клиентскую часть веб-приложения, используя библиотеку ws(веб-сокеты), однако никак это сделать не удается. Подскажите, как решается данная проблема и в чем моя ошибка? Заранее спасибо.

```
var http = require("http");

var nodeStatic = require("node-static");

var fileServer = new nodeStatic.Server("./public", {
        cache: 3600
    });

var server = http.createServer(handler);

var webSocketServer = require("ws").Server;

var wss = new webSocketServer({server:server});

function handler(req, res) {
        console.log(req.url);
        if (req.url = "/") {
        req.on("end", function() {
            fileServer.serve(req, res);
        }).resume();
    }


wss.broadcast = function broadcast(data) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function(client) {
        client.send(data); 
    });
};

wss.on("connection", function(socket) {

    socket.on("message", function(message) {
        wss.clients.forEach(function(client) {
            client.send(message);
        });
    });
});
};

server.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on port 8000");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
    var io = require('socket.io')(app);
    var fs = require('fs');

    app.listen(8080);

    function handler (req, res) {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
            function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    return res.end('Error loading index.html');
                }

                res.writeHead(200);
                res.end(data);
            });
    }

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
        socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

взято где то  в примерах... подойдет?
вообще можно поднять 2 сервера, https и ws, первый запрос брать с http дальше поднимать на ws от клиента.